# Can i continuously call a function slot using Qt?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I want to check an object value using C++ and Qt in GUI. So for this i want to continuously call the function so that i can check the object value and to emit a Signal. 
it there any way to call the function Slot continuously without connecting it with any push button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a timer?

Edit: My bad, codes not exactly right.

```
QTimer t;
connect(&t, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(checkValue()));
t.start(100); // Set interval to whatever you want
```

Comment: You should use rachet's code, its more complete than my answer.

Comment: It is working thanks Frank ..... actually i just Needed with a simple code to implement thanks for the help .....

Answer (score 1):

use a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtimer.html)

```
class MyObject : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

    QTimer timer_;

    MyObject(QObject* parent = 0) :QObject(parent), timer_(){
        timer_.setInterval(1000);
        timer_.setSingleShot(false);
        timer_start();
        connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyObject::timerSignal);
    }


  signals:
    void timerSignal(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off with letting the `changeValue` function emit a `valueChanged` signal itself, and not poll for the change, but instead be notified of it. You don't want to be reminded the value has stayed the same (by calling Slot continuously) but instead you want to do something when the value changes.

Adding a timer for this kind of thing is extremely messy.

Comment: This is the better way to do it. I'm confused if the OP is asking about polling a GUI element or polling something internal to update the GUI.

Comment: @Frank I'd write a small example, but my Qt is extremely rusty, and I think it'd take quite a while to get right :-P.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean you. I meant the original question. I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Actually the Problem is that the object whose value i want to check is not in GUI it is the part of other class. so thats why i want to check it each time to check either it got changed or not ?

Comment: @user2595530 `signal`s aren't exclusive to the GUI. Quite the contrary.

Comment: now what i am doing it to using the timer and to check the value after a specific interval of time ... so then emits the Signal when it detects the value got changed so then i can call a specific function now whén Signal emits...

Comment: @user2595530 what changes the variable in question? I think it's that part of the code that should emit the signal.